Bench start is not running properly
I followed the installation steps given in the
documentation.
I installed redis, mariadb, yarn, wkhtmltopdf, python3, and bench.
Project boilerplate has created by running below command:
pip3 install frappe-bench

After this, I run bench start command, that is not running properly.
Below is the screenshot, where you can see it stopped running.

I tried to find the solution, but did not find any.
Please help me to understand and fix the issue.

The issue was resolved by moving my project from OneDrive to a local directory. It is now running properly.

The documentation provides a detailed list of requirements in the Prerequisite section. It does not work with python version 3.12 or above. So my suggestion is to create a virtual environment with python version 3.11 and try again.
You can also tryout the dockerized version by following this guide.

I am using python version 3.10.10

I have checked through version 3.11.6 for frappe version-15 and it works fine
